# Reset mysql root password after phpmyadmin corrupted it

Tags: mysql, password, root, reset

So I tried to change my mysql root password for the first time using a advanced pattern and it looks like phpmyadmin stripped the password on save.  Now I can't login under root.

I am using RHEL 5 and it seems that all the instructions I keep finding don't work.

When I run the following command.  I get

```
[root@vault ~]# mysqld_safe –skip-grant-tables -u root &
[1] 30274
[root@vault ~]# Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
STOPPING server from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
110705 20:38:37  mysqld ended
```

Does anyone know of a workaround that works?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the tail of the MySQL error log?  On Ubuntu this will do it - not sure if RHEL puts it in the same place:    tail /var/log/mysql.err

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo

```
mysqld_safe –skip-grant-tables -u root &
```

should read

```
mysqld_safe -–skip-grant-tables -u root &
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently addressed:

[Lost MySQL password](https://serverfault.com/questions/287225/lost-mysql-password/287235#287235)

If the --skip-grant-tables doesn't work as a flag, see above link.